# RxJS equivalent of RxJava's onBackpressureBuffer

Tags: react-native, rxjs, rx-java2

In React Native, I'm dealing with events generated at 200 Hz by the a bluetooth IoT. I need to [keep up](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html) for no more than 2 minutes.

There's the overhead of pushing them to JavaScript through the bridge and the JS processing, that is taken care of on the Java (Android) side with [onBackpressureBuffer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onBackpressureBuffer())().

I need to do the same on the Javascript Side. I can't loose events, so they should be buffered

What would be the operator to apply on the event emitter before subscription to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: It seems like you could use `concatMap` and put processing of each event inside it event though it's a little weird.  `concatMap` won't start processing the next event until the current one completes.

Comment: I don't really get the problem. How can you loose the events? Once they are scheduled on the event loop, they will eventually get a slice of processing. Can you post more details? For example: if you use an `interval` stream that pushes events at 1 second but your processing takes longer (2 sec), you won't loose the events.

Comment: I'm not saying I'm loosing events, strictly speaking. On the Java side, without the backpressure strategy, processing stops with rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException.

Comment: Last time I checked, RxJS did not support backpressure. A lossless approach could be to buffer with size/time and hope you can process the batch fast enough. A lossy workaround would be to sample the input with a reasonable frequency.

Comment: @akarnokd I've found [this](https://itnext.io/lossless-backpressure-in-rxjs-b6de30a1b6d4). Looks promising for a solution without using a buffer.

Comment: I ended not using RxJS at all, considering that all the buffering should be done on native side.